# Google Chrome unauthorized response causes a popup

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, passport.js, windows-server-2012

My tech stack:
Node 5.12.0, runs on Windows Server
ReactJs application, Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100

Scenario:
1. A user tries to login with **bad credentials**
2. The Node application checks the request and tries to match with DB  (Basic Authentication using [passportJs](http://www.passportjs.org/) )
3. Node application returns a 401 (Unauthorized) response
4. Chrome pops up a credentials form

**See Attached .gif**

Happens also on IE, not on FF.

How can I prevent displaying the popup?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very loooooooong investigation it seems like a default browser behavior when getting a 401 error code AND a response header "WWW-Authenticate" with "Basic" value.

Altering the response fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi there, I got the same issue, but with a different tech-stack (should be no problem). Is there any other possibility to fix that error? btw: firefox does not show the popup-box for credentials.

Comment: Hi, I can't think of any other reasons for that.